# How to Fix JSON Key Values without double-quotes?

Tags: python, json, regex

I currently have JSON in the below format.
Some of the Key values are NOT properly formatted as they are missing double quotes (")

How do I fix these key values to have double-quotes on them?

```
    {      
Name: "test",
Address: "xyz",
"Age": 40,
"Info": "test"
}
```

Required:

```
    {      
"Name": "test",
"Address": "xyz",
"Age": 40,
"Info": "test"
}
```

Using the below post, I was able to find such key values in the above INVALID JSON.
However, I could NOT find an efficient way to replace these found values with double-quotes.

```
s = "Example: String"
out = re.findall(r'\w+:', s)
```

[How to Escape Double Quote inside JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150405/python-how-to-escape-double-quote-inside-json-string-value)

Comment: are the keys at the start of the line, everytime?

Comment: No Jean, a few of the keys are hidden in between. I do NOT have access to change source format. Hence, have to process it at my end.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
import re
data = """{ Name: "test", Address: "xyz"}"""
print( re.sub("(\w+):", r'"\1":',  data) )
```

**Output:**

```
{ "Name": "test", "Address": "xyz"}
```

Comment: This regex approach is very unsafe. It will alter values that happen to contain colons. See my answer for a safe solution.

Comment: In JavaScript: `const result = jsonWithoutDoubleQuotes.replace(/((?=\D)\w+):/gm, '"$1":');`

Answer (score 8):

You can use PyYaml. Since JSON is a subset of Yaml, pyyaml may overcome the lack of quotes.

Example

```py
import yaml

dirty_json = """
     {
  key: "value",
  "key2": "value"
}
"""
yaml.load(dirty_json, yaml.SafeLoader)
```

Comment: This solution worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: this is so ugly and so beautiful at the same time. I'll definitely use it :D

Comment: This also worked for me and seems more likely to be safe than the accepted regex solution from both malicious scripts and just bad assumptions.

Answer (score 6):

You can use online formatter. I know most of them are throwing error for not having double quotes but below one seems handling it nicely!

[JSON Formatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html)

Comment: I'm impressed, one of few tools that accepts invalid JSON as input

Answer (score 5):

I had few more issues that I faced in my JSON.
Thought of sharing the final solution that worked for me.

```
jsonStr = re.sub("((?=\D)\w+):", r'"\1":',  jsonStr)
jsonStr = re.sub(": ((?=\D)\w+)", r':"\1"',  jsonStr)
```

1. First Line will fix this double-quotes issue for the Key. i.e.
   **Name**: "test"
2. Second Line will fix  double-quotes issue for the value. i.e. "Info": **test**

Also, above will exclude double-quoting within date timestamp which have : (colon) in them.

Comment: It works well for me including the timestamp cases where timestamp has a : in it but it is failing for another key value pair in json data where value contains : in it. e.g. address:"2600:0000:cf02:ff64:0000:0000:345e:e820" . This regex converting this value to address":\"2600:0000:"cf02":4"e3f":7"c7a":2887:97"c9":40cd\" .

Answer (score 0):

The regex approach can be brittle. I suggest you find a library that can parse the JSON text that is missing quotes.

For example, in Kotlin 1.4, the standard way to parse a JSON string is using `Json.decodeFromString`. However, you can use `Json { isLenient = true }.decodeFromString` to relax the requirements for quotes. Here is a complete example in JUnit.

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

@Serializable
data class Widget(val x: Int, val y: String)

class JsonTest {

    @Test
    fun `Parsing Json`() {
        val w: Widget = Json.decodeFromString("""{"x":123, "y":"abc"}""")
        Assertions.assertEquals(123, w.x)
        Assertions.assertEquals("abc", w.y)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Parsing Json missing quotes`() {
        // Json.decodeFromString("{x:123, y:abc}") failed to decode due to missing quotes
        val w: Widget = Json { isLenient = true }.decodeFromString("{x:123, y:abc}")
        Assertions.assertEquals(123, w.x)
        Assertions.assertEquals("abc", w.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: Although you're correct that regex can be brittle for parsing recursive structures like JSON, this question is about Python, not Kotlin.