# How to insert a missing delimiter character in an invalid JSON in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program that can identify which delimiter characters are missing and insert them in their respective position within a `JSON` file. So, for instance, let's suppose my `JSON` looks like this:

```
{
    "array": [{
        "id": "123",
        "info": {
            "name": "something"
        }
        "address": {
            "street": "Dreamland"
        }
    }]
}
```

This `JSON` is invalid since there's no `,` between `}` and `"address"`.

Here's the thing: when I try to use `json.loads(my_json.read())`, it'll throw a `JSONDecodeError` exception, which will tell me what character is missing and at what character position it should be, like so:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 7 column 9 (char 116)
```

I've already tried printing `my_json.seek(116)` which didn't work at all, it just printed the number 116.

So my question is: is it possible to actually use the exception error message to fix the `JSON` since it shows what delimiter character is missing and at what position it should be, or should I just use a stack data structure to keep track of all possible delimiters and insert the missing ones? Or is there a better way to do this?

I've seen other questions in here like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514910/how-do-i-automatically-fix-an-invalid-json-string) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947760/python-how-to-fix-json-key-values-without-double-quotes) but the first one is an encoding issue, which is not my case, and the second one is for a very specific case.

Sorry if some of this seems dumb, I'm still learning how to code in Python.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the string at the position where the delimiter `','` is missing (stored as the `pos` attribute of exception object), and join them with `','`:

```
import json

s = '[{"a":1}{"b":2}{"c":3}]'
while True:
    try:
        data = json.loads(s)
        break
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        if not e.args[0].startswith("Expecting ',' delimiter:"):
            raise
        s = ','.join((s[:e.pos], s[e.pos:]))
print(s)
print(data)
```

This outputs:

```
[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}]
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}]
```

Comment: You can also use the `colno`, `lineno`, and/or `pos` attributes of the `JSONDecodeError` to save on some regex-ing. To make it even more simple, you can also pre-minify it to get rid of the whitespace, then you can just use `pos` to find the insertion point: `minified = ''.join(x.strip() for x in s.splitlines())`

Comment: Updated to use the `pos` attribute as suggested. Thanks! Don't think minification makes any difference though--the `pos` attribute is just as accurate even with redundant white spaces.

Comment: Good point! For some reason I thought `pos` and `colno` were the same.