# How to extract values from a String that cannot be converted to Json

Tags: java, json, string

While processing the DialogFlow Response object, I get the below given string as **textPayload**. If this is a Json string, I can easily convert it to a JSONObject and then extract the values. However, could not convert this to a Json Object. How do I get the values for the keys in this string? What is a good way to parse this string in **Java**?

> String to be processed

```
Dialogflow Response : id: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
lang: "en"
session_id: "XXXXX"
timestamp: "2020-04-26T16:38:26.162Z"
result {
  source: "agent"
  resolved_query: "Yes"
  score: 1.0
  parameters {
  }
  contexts {
    name: "enaccaccountblocked-followup"
    lifespan: 1
    parameters {
    }
  }
  metadata {
    intent_id: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    intent_name: "EN : ACC : Freezing Process - Yes"
    end_conversation: true
    webhook_used: "false"
    webhook_for_slot_filling_used: "false"
    is_fallback_intent: "false"
  }
  fulfillment {
    speech: "Since you have been permanently blocked, please request to  unblock your account"
    messages {
      lang: "en"
      type {
        number_value: 0.0
      }
      speech {
        string_value: "Since you have been permanently blocked, please request to  unblock your account."
      }
    }
  }
}
status {
  code: 200
  error_type: "success"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to valid json, then map using one of the many libraries out there.

You'll only need to:

- replace `"Dialogflow Response :"` with `{`
- add `}` to the end
- add commas between attributes, ie

  - at the end of every line with a `":"`
  - after `"}"`, except when the next non-whitespace is also `"}"`

Jackson (at least) can be configured to allow quotes around attribute names as optional.

Deserializing to a `Map<String, Object>` works for all valid json (except an array, which this isn't).

Comment: Yeah..Need to write regex for all these.

Comment: @Kabilesh the first needs no regex, or the second - just `+ "}"`. The 3rd `replaceAll("(?m)^.*:.*", "$0,")` the last `replaceAll("}\\s*([^\\s}])", "},$1")`

Comment: That will save a lot of time. And to add double quotes as @Chritian mentioned what will be the regex?

Comment: What double quotes? where do you think you need them?

Comment: In a Json it should be **"lang": "en"** not **lang: "en"** right?? The key and value both should have double quotes around them.

Comment: @Kabilesh as per my answer, "no", but it depends on the library you are using. I would recommend Jackson, which allows unquoted attribute name by configuring the mapper like this: `objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);`. I don't know about other libraries - they may or may not support it. You can do as you please, but my motto is "less code is good"; if you can get it working with less code, that's a good thing.

Comment: Okay. I was using `org.json.JSONObject`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly the issue here is that the keys do not have quotations marks, hence, a JSON parser will reject this.

Since the keys all start on a new line with some white-space and all end with a colon : you can fix this easily with a regular expression.

See [How to Fix JSON Key Values without double-quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947760/how-to-fix-json-key-values-without-double-quotes)

You can then parse it to a Map via

```
Map<String, Object> map 
  = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){});
```

(but I assume you are aware of this).

Comment: Yes. That's exactly the problem. Need to write a regex.

Comment: But the regex is comparably simple here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for TextPayload object like this.

```
public class TextPayload {
   private int session_id;
   private String lang;
   private String timestamp;
   private String[] metadata ;
   //Other attributes
   //getters setters
}
```

Then using an `ObjectMapper` extract the values from textpayload like this:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TextPayload textPayload = mapper.readValue(output, User.class);
```

To utilize `ObjectMapper` and hands on with it follow [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html)

Comment: won't work. it's too far from being valid json to be mapped

Comment: Yes. I Understand that. But the problem is, this is not a **Json** nor a **Json String**. This is just a **String** that is aligned properly. How can I process this with **ObjectMapper**?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the nodejs package parse-dialogflow-log to parse the textResponse string.

1. replace "Dialogflow Response :" with "{"
2. add "}" to the end
3. run the package on the result and you'll get a nice json.