# How to fix missing double quotes issue when parsing JSON data?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am running a piece of code in Python3 where I am consuming JSON data from the source. I don't have control over the source. While reading the json data I am getting following error:

> simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2

Here is the code

```
import logging
import simplejson as json
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',        
        api_version=(1,0,0))

consumer.subscribe(['Test_Topic-1'])

for message in consumer:
    msg_str=message.value    
    y = json.loads(msg_str)
    print(y["city_name"])
```

As I can not change the source, I need to fix it at my end. I found out this post helpful as my data contains the timestamps with `:` in it: [How to Fix JSON Key Values without double-quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947760/how-to-fix-json-key-values-without-double-quotes/50965425#50965425)

But it also fails for some values in my json data as those values contain `:` in it. e.g.

```
address:"1600:3050:rf02:hf64:h000:0000:345e:d321"
```

Is there any way where I can add double quotes to keys in my json data?

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please

Comment: - Edited the original question and added the code I am using.

Comment: you can try with module `dirtyjson` - it can fix some mistakes.

Comment: You still haven't shown us an example of your input. In any case, it sounds like what you're dealing with _isn't JSON_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use module [dirtyjson](https://github.com/codecobblers/dirtyjson) - it can fix some mistakes.

```
import dirtyjson

d = dirtyjson.loads('{address:"1600:3050:rf02:hf64:h000:0000:345e:d321"}')

print( d['address'] )

d = dirtyjson.loads('{abc:"1:2:3:4", efg:"5:6:7:8", "hij":"foo"}')

print( d['abc'] )
```

---

It creates `AttributedDict` so it may need `dict()` to create normal dictionary

```
d = dirtyjson.loads('{abc:"1:2:3:4", efg:"5:6:7:8", "hij":"foo"}')

print( d )

print( dict(d) )
```

Result:

```
AttributedDict([('abc', '1:2:3:4'), ('efg', '5:6:7:8'), ('hij', 'foo')])

{'abc': '1:2:3:4', 'efg': '5:6:7:8', 'hij': 'foo'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you have strings like this:

```
{abc:"1:2:3:4", efg:"5:6:7:8", "hij":"foo"}
```

which are not valid JSON. You could try to repair it with a regular expression substitution:

```
import re
jtxt_bad ='{abc:"1:2:3:4", efg:"5:6:7:8", "hij":"foo", klm:"bar"\n}'
jtxt = re.sub(r'\b([a-zA-Z]+):("[^"]+"[,\n}])', r'"\1":\2', jtxt_bad)

print(f'Original: {jtxt_bad}\nRepaired: {jtxt}')
```

The output of this is:

```
Original: {abc:"1:2:3:4", efg:"5:6:7:8", "hij":"foo", klm:"bar"
}
Repaired: {"abc":"1:2:3:4", "efg":"5:6:7:8", "hij":"foo", "klm":"bar"
}
```

The regular expression `\b([a-zA-Z]+):("[^"]+"[,\}])` means: boundary, followed by one or more letters, followed by a `:`, followed by double-quoted string, followed by one of `,`, `}`, `\n`. However, this will fail if there is a quote inside the string, such as `"1:\"2:3"`.