# Parse unquoted string as json and get it's properties values

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, .net-6.0

I'm getting unquoted json string with dynamic properties from API and I need to check if specific property exist, and if it does I need to get it's value.
For example I'm getting this string:

```
"{overridedCondition:used,makerAndModelMissing:true}"
```

I need to check for 'overridedCondition', if it exist I need to get it's value.
I tried something like this but I'm getting exception like 'Error parsing undefined value. Path 'overridedCondition'':

`var json = "{overridedCondition:used,makerAndModelMissing:true}";`

`var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);`

I also tried parsing it with

`JObject.Parse(json);`

but that didn't worked either.

Does anyone have some suggestion on how to parse this string so I'm able to access it's values.

I'm using .net 6 for this project. Thanks

Comment: Are all your striings like this one or you can have some more complicated?

Comment: The problem is that your "json string" is not actually JSON, it's malformed.  You can't parse a malformed JSON string with a JSON parser, you'll get an error.  In order to parse that, you need to know the actual grammar.  For instance, how are string values that include colons represented e.g. ISO 8601 time strings like `18:18:24Z`?  Strings with embedded commas?  How are arrays represented?  Nested objects?

Comment: If your inputs are simple key/value pairs with no nesting and no embedded quotes, you might just parse them manually with a string split rather than with a serializer.  Or use a regex to fix the input, see e.g. [How to Fix JSON Key Values without double-quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50947760).

Comment: Correct JSON: `{ "overridedCondition": "used", "makerAndModelMissing": true }`. See: [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). Shouldn't the first property be named `overriddenCondition`? "overrided" does not sound English.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes, you're right regarding the name, it is a typo.

Comment: @dbc That is the issue it is a dynamic string, I never know what I'm going to get, it is a peace of some scrape data.

I ended up fixing string via regex, with help of the question you suggested, to add quotes and  than I was able to do JObject.Parse(json).

From there it is straight forward to achieve the logic I need. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

if all your string are like the one you posted, you can  try this code

```
   var s = "{overridedCondition:used,makerAndModelMissing:true}";

    var jObj = new JObject(s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2)
                            .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            .Select(x => x.Split(":", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries))
                            .Select(x => new JProperty(x[0], x[1])));

    string overridedCondition = (string)jObj["overridedCondition"];
```

if you need a  valid json string

```
    string json = jObj.ToString();
```

UPDATE

You can try to fix a json string as you want and parse it to a JObject, but  IMHO it is not a reliable way

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(s.Replace("{", "{\"")
                          .Replace("}", "\"}")
                          .Replace(":", "\":\"")
                          .Replace(",", "\",\""));
```

Comment: The string is the result of scrape data so I never know what I'm going to get or even if I'm going to get anything so I ended up fixing string to proper JSON format and parsing it.

Comment: What do you have it is not an invalid json string, it is just a string. IMHO it is not the best way try to convert a string to a json string and after this parse it to JObject. It is much more relailable to create a JObject from a string with delimeters. You have much more ways to validate an original string.